# Oracle SQL Question to get date difference between two rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the data as below in a table

```
name     Phone    last login      created date
Joe      9259241517    21-Mar-2023   15-mar-2023 10:15:00
Pete     9259241518    22-Mar-2023   15-mar-2023 11:15:00
Joe      9259241517    21-Mar-2023   15-mar-2023 09:15:00
Pete     9259241518    22-Mar-2023   15-mar-2023 07:35:00
```

I need to find the rows which are having < 2 hours of difference in the created date. In the above case, I need to get only rows of "Joe"

Appreciate your help,
Regards

Comment: what if joe has thee rows?

Comment: Please post your current code and describe what is the issue with it. This is not a codewriting service

Comment: If Joe has three rows then all three would be returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work.

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS';


 with data( name,  create_date, last_login ) AS (
     SELECT 'John', TO_DATE('2023-03-21 10:11:13','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('2023-03-21 17:48:09','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
     SELECT 'Jane', TO_DATE('2023-03-21 10:11:13','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('2023-03-21 11:11:09','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
     SELECT 'Mary', TO_DATE('2023-03-21 10:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('2023-03-21 12:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL
     )
   --
   -- end of sample data
   --
   select *
  from   data
  where  last_login-create_date < (2/24)


NAME CREATE_DATE          LAST_LOGIN
---- -------------------- --------------------
Jane 21-MAR-2023 10:11:13 21-MAR-2023 11:11:09
```